# Всегда ли нужно использовать длинное тире?

Tags: пунктуация

В литературе используется длинное тире (—; Alt+0151).

Но MS Word часто заменяет дефис именно на короткое тире (–) между, например, подлежащим и сказуемым: *Дуб – дерево*. Или же это влияние правил зарубежных типографий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видите ли, в чём тут дело. В реестр кодифицированных знаков препинания входит только два вида горизонтальных чёрточек: тире и дефис. Все остальные чёрточки — это уже вопросы типографии, то есть технические, ни в каких пунктуационных справочниках не прописанные. Прочитать, когда что используется, [можно тут](https://webstyle.sfu-kras.ru/tire-defis).

Что касается "Дуб — дерево", то здесь нужен не дефис, а именно тире (по правилам пунктуации), и именно длинное тире (по правилам типографики).